# Can I apply for a B2 visa if I was previously on F1?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

I was in the US from August 2012 on F1 visa. I did my masters and worked for a couple of years, all on F1 before leaving for good in October 2016. Though I left in October, my work permit was valid until December and visa until June 2017. My company applied for H1 when I was working in US and it didn't get picked. 
Now I'm working in the UK and would like to visit my sister's family back in the US. Can I apply for B2? Will there be any issues because I was in the US before?
PS: For clarity, I don't hold any valid US visa anymore.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Are you British?

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning it, I'm an Indian, working as a dependent on husband's tier 2 ICT

Answer (score 1):

There are no restrictions for you to apply for a B1/B2; I know many people that were students (F1) and later would like to visit for tourism or just to get in touch with their college friends.

The fact that your employer applied for a H1 and was not successful has no bearing on your application, as it is not a rejection (the H1 is a lottery system).

Since you complied with your previous visa's rules - you actually have good history with the US.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Burhan Khalid. Keeping my fingers crossed.